# boton agregar no funciona

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Bueno sigo haciendo un crud de calificaciones y resulta que el boton sigue sin funcionar y ya lo empece de nuevo, primero aqui esta el codigo de mi base de datos:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
            CREATE TABLE `pruebas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `matricula` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre_alumno` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;



INSERT INTO `pruebas` (`id`, `matricula`, `nombre_alumno`) VALUES
(39, '8746531', '');

    ALTER TABLE `pruebas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `pruebas`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=40;
COMMIT;
```

ahora este es mi codigo index donde tengo la modal para agregar un nuevo alumno:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agrega nueva persona</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <label>MATRICULA</label>
            <input type="text" name="matricula" id="matricula" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
            <label>NOMBRE</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control input-sm" required="">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="guardarnuevo">
        Agregar
        </button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y aqui esta mi conexion:

```
<?php 
        function conexion(){
            $servidor="localhost";
            $usuario="root";
            $password="";
            $bd="control_escolar1";
            $conexion=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$password,$bd);
            return $conexion;
        }

 ?>
```

y aqui esta el codigo de agregar datos, mediante un metodo post que segun yo esta bien estructurado, con los nombres correctamente, este es el codigo:
segun yo este php esta bien hecho, y segun lo que me dijo mi profesor.

```
<?php 

    require_once "conexion.php";
    $conexion=conexion();
    $matricula=$_POST['matricula'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre_alumno'];


    $sql="INSERT into pruebas (matricula,nombre_alumno) values ('$matricula','$nombre')";
    echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

 ?>
```

y estas son mis funciones js:

```
function agregardatos(matricula,nombre_alumno){

    cadena="matricula=" + matricula + 
            "&nombre" + nombre_alumno +


    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"php/agregarDatos.php",
        data:cadena,
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php');
                 $('#buscador').load('componentes/buscador.php');
                alertify.success("agregado con exito :)");
            }else{
                alertify.error("Fallo el servidor :(");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

ahora otro problema que tengo es que la matricula si la esta agregando a la base de datos pero el nombre no, cuando cargo una matricula la agrega bien pero el nombre no, y ahi es donde no se porque, o que es lo que tengo mal, porque le pregunte a un profesor y el me dijo que iba bien, que no deberia tener error, pero pues es obvio que estoy mal en algo, pero no se en que, les agradeceria mucho su ayuda por favor, gracias por las respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

En la petición estas pasando `nombre` y recuperas `nombre_alumno`.

Cambia tu php de insertar en BBDD por

```
<?php 

    require_once "conexion.php";
    $conexion=conexion();
    $matricula=$_POST['matricula'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre']; // Aqui el cambio para solucionar tu error.


    $sql="INSERT into pruebas (matricula,nombre_alumno) values ('$matricula','$nombre')";
    echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

 ?>
```

Comment: Hola disculpe que pregunte de nuevo, pero no funciono, sigue sin insertar nada y ya no se que podria ser, ¿hay alguna otra cosa que podria ser?

Comment: ¿Que vale ' $result'  despues de la query?